# How to print the hashmap values from the order they inserted into the hashmap

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have a HashMap which have strings as key and value,

```
HashMap dataSet = new HashMap();

dataSet.put("A1", "Aania");
dataSet.put("X1", "Abatha");
dataSet.put("C1", "Acathan");
dataSet.put("S1", "Adreenas");
```

I want to print it as the order it is inserted into the HashMap, So the output should be like,

```
A1, Aania
X1, Abatha
C1, Acathan
S1, Adreenas
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead, which will preserve the insertion order. You can't do what you ask for with a standard `HashMap`.

> This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

So the first line of your code would become:

```
Map dataSet = new LinkedHashMap();
```

You might also want to add generics as a good practice:

```
Map<String, String> dataSet = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use LinkedHashMap and print data. Using LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap is not a problem. I can use LinkedHashMap if it do the work

Comment: @Roshanck I have added some code. You can print the map: `System.out.println(dataSet);`

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to retrieve the keys and values from as LinkedHashMap in insertion order? Println will just utilize toString which doesn't help when you need to work with the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't a hashmap has no internal order

You will have to use another implementation of Map

Comment: You forgot to mention *which* other implementation of Map to use.